# Installing Laravel on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using Windows 7.
I am following Laracasts - Laravel Setup for Newbs https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-installation-for-newbs but when it comes to the 4:25 mark where i enter `php artisan serve` I get the following showing up.

```
C:\Users\Pierce\Desktop\laravel-demo>php artisan serve
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
[Wed Mar 19 00:29:46 2014] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 <reason: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.>
```

I have XAMPP installed straight from the box and followed the instructions in the video. What happens that I get stopped here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php artisan serve` is a command to fire up PHP's own web server. If you are using XAMPP already, I would suggest using it's built-in Apache web server and then run Laravel through that. There are plenty of documents online on how to setup XAMPP.

As for your error, it's Windows UAC that is blocking it. Disable UAC or set or exception for your program.

Comment: So best just install in my htdocs and run through localhost as I would have with older php stuff?

Comment: Basically yes. The best approach would be to create a vhost in Apache and run it through there.

Comment: Thanks. I hate when tutorials do one thing then something else happens

Answer (score 4):

you can use another port, something like this

> php artisan serve --port="8888"

this port work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Buy a mac

Else

2. Delete XAMPP
3. Install Laragon (http://laragon.org/)

All problems solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you avoid using htdocs folder of xampp. Because in this method, I could not route to other pages. So you should do this, **php artisan serve --port="8888"** or other port (as mininoz said).